# How to mark the first and last dates in date series

Tags: r, date

```
data<-data.frame(
ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
Date=c("date1", "date2","date3","date4","date1", "date2","date3","date1",
       "date2","date3","date4","date5"))
```

I have an ordered date series for each individual. I would like to mark in front of the first date of each individual `f`, in front of the last date `l` and in front of the other dates `o`,to have such a table below:

```
    ID  Date TypeOfDate
1   1 date1          f
2   1 date2          o
3   1 date3          o
4   1 date4          l
5   2 date1          f
6   2 date2          o
7   2 date3          l
8   3 date1          f
9   3 date2          o
10  3 date3          o
11  3 date4          o
12  3 date5          l
```

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention it. I have a lot of individuals with only one row (date) in my real dataset

Comment: If there is only one row by ID it must be `f`

Comment: The answer that you checked gives "l" if there is one ID.

Comment: Yes, it is true. I hadn't thought about the option of only one row per ID, even the answer is consistent with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would my approach with the tidyverse.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data<-data.frame(
  ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
  Date=c("date1", "date2","date3","date4","date1", "date2","date3","date1",
         "date2","date3","date4","date5"))

data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(row_id=row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(TypeOfDate=case_when(row_id==max(row_number()) ~ "l",
                             row_id==min(row_number()) ~ "f",
                             TRUE ~ as.character("o")))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>       ID Date  row_id TypeOfDate
#>    <dbl> <chr>  <int> <chr>     
#>  1     1 date1      1 f         
#>  2     1 date2      2 o         
#>  3     1 date3      3 o         
#>  4     1 date4      4 l         
#>  5     2 date1      1 f         
#>  6     2 date2      2 o         
#>  7     2 date3      3 l         
#>  8     3 date1      1 f         
#>  9     3 date2      2 o         
#> 10     3 date3      3 o         
#> 11     3 date4      4 o         
#> 12     3 date5      5 l
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>